# Electron API accessible from client apps (other client electron apps in a network)

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Here is what I am trying to accomplish. Build an `electron` app that I can install on the server and on client machines.

The **server** install will have the app install as normal.

The **client** install will be configured to access the `electron` API on the server machine.

This way you can basically the same code base to install server and client versions.

Is this possible?

Comment: What kind of app are you trying to build? I don't see a need for the electron app to be on the server. I'd just use node.js on the server and the electron apps could consume it's API via HTTP like normal. Would that work for your use case?

Comment: Yes.. that could also work. Just wanted to take advantage of the fact that Electron has an install package that will automatically install node and other node libs needed for the app. If I could reuse that to install the server packages then that would be great.

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to write a bash or cmd script (depending on the OS) to install node.js, run `npm install`, and then start the node server. You could also write a script like that, run it on a build server, and zip it and distribute it.

Comment: Servers where I want to install are always offline. If I could use the packaging Electron provides then I could solve the problem.